# The controller for path '/Account/Login' was not found or does not implement IController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

..but I don't **have** a Login Controller!

I get it when I throw a custom error.

I mean.. yeah.  I started my project from a sample project that had one, and I deleted the Account Controller, its view, and even any code that referred to "Login", (and even any entries in the web.config that may mention it) and it comes up with this error.

where else would I check?

**Update:**  I am using Active Directory instead of a login form.

Comment: Check the web.config. Wait !! Do a solution level search for "Login"

Comment: tried that.  no luck..

Comment: Clean your solution. Delete Temp files. Restart VS

Comment: Have you checked the Startup.Auth.cs? look for `CookieAuthenticationOptions`.

Comment: The best way is to create a new project and take care to the check box that tell if you want to add individual account authentication before validating project creation.

Comment: Check also your `Properties` (Web tab) to see if a Startup page has been set

Comment: If you don't have a login page/controller and don't need one, check if any controller actions have the `[Authorize]` attribute above them.

Comment: @Lars,  actually I am using the [Authorize] attribute.. or rather a custom one where I am simply telling it to return false at the moment.  it is this authorization error that is the problem.  I can't seem to figure out why its wanting to go to Account/Login

Comment: @Kevin, you want users to be logged in to access a controller action, but your custom attribute always returns false, so they are never logged in?

Comment: I'm having it return false for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok. so it seems like my issue was with the fact that I am using custom `[Authorize]` attributes, and I didn't have a login page **at all**.  I am using Active Directory.

According to @Lars & @Shani, apparently I need to somehow point back to one.

Unfortunately I can't as I don't have one, and it would be useless to create one.  So I came up with a method that works with my situation. In my custom `[Authorize]` attribute, I'm returning a `RedirectToRouteResult` that goes to my custom Error page:

```
 protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);

        if (!_authorized)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                controller = "ErrorPage",
                action = "Unauthorized"
            }));
        }
    }
```

I'm sure there is a few different ways to do this, but this is what I'm going with this at the moment..

Comment: I'm glad you fixed the issue. This seems like a good solution for your current setup with AD login.

Answer (score 1):

Just add to your web config file these lines:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/home/Login" timeout="2880"></forms>
</authentication>
```

in the loginUrl enter the right login page destination and it will redirect all of the requests marked [Authorized] there and not to Account/Login.

Answer (score 0):

Do a global search for @Html.Action("Login", "AccountController") and delete that.

It could be that some views still referring that Login method in AccountController.

Answer (score 0):

Check if any controller classes or actions have the `[Authorize]` attribute above them.

If a user requests an action where the attribute is present, they will be redirected to a login-page if they aren't already logged in. But if you don't have a login page (and if you don't need users to be logged in) then you shouldn't use this attribute.

Comment: how does it know the login page to redirect to?

Comment: If I recall correctly, MVC automatically redirects to `"~/Account/Login/"`unless another action is entered in web.config.

Comment: Lars, do you have any links that might give some weight to why you are saying I shouldn't use the attribute if I don't have a login page? I'm using Active Directory.  It is just that some users on the domain are not authorized.  I'm weeding them out with a custom authorize attribute and returning false in AuthorizeCore if they are not allowed in.

Comment: From your description, I assumed you had this issue because you were using the attribute without any way for users to log in. Now that you mention that you authenticate with Active Directory it makes more sense :-)

Comment: @Kevin have you investigated if anything in the route config points to a login action?

Comment: I did. the only route in there is to the main page.

Answer (score 0):

If Your app is configured to use authentication mechanism other than Forms, like WIF, try to remove forms authentication module from the configuration.

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
       <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
```